# I can't get data from POST requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, http-headers, http-post

I need to get the data from this request: https://utp.sberbank-ast.ru/TNG/List/PurchaseList
Namely from this post request: https://utp.sberbank-ast.ru/TNG/SearchQuery/PurchaseList

but when I try to get it, only {'result': 'error', 'data': 'No parameters to initialize the request'} comes out

I use the headers of my browser, namely:

```
headers = { "Accept": "/", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", "Accept-Language": "ru,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7", "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/119.0.0.0' }
```

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

headers = {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "ru,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7",
        "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/119.0.0.0'
    }
response = requests.post('https://utp.sberbank-ast.ru/TNG/SearchQuery/PurchaseList', headers=headers)
print(response.json())
```

I put the headers that I got through.headers that were received via F12 on the site and the Request Headers field, in these cases the code output `"requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))"`. I also tried to take headers via F12 on the site and the Response Headers field. In this case, it outputs {'result': 'error', 'data': 'No parameters to initialize the request'}.I tried to get the data using get, but this way it outputs an empty field.